# why output write data is way more then input data in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am inserting 310GB of csv file data from HDFS to cassandra, I have 3 node spark cluster with each node of 32GB RAM and 24 cores. The output data size is more than input data, what could be the reason? Is it because that spark is running multiple task for same block of data and writing it back to cassandra? If yes how to check the calculation, is it possible from spark web ui ? like for 310GB of data , what amount of extra data spark might write ?
[spark job status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxj4V.png)

```
val spark = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName(job.name)
.config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandraHost)
.config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", cassandraPort)
.getOrCreate()
val csv: DataFrame = spark.read
.format(fileFormat)
.option("header", job.header)
.option("inferSchema", job.inferSchema)
.option("delimiter", job.delimiter)
.load(sourceFile)
.filter(job.filter.getOrElse("1==1"))
.distinct()
.na
.fill("unknown")
val columns: Array[Column] = csv.columns
.map(c =>
  job.schema.get(c) match {
    case Some(newName) => csv.col(c).as(newName.toLowerCase)
    case None => null
  })
.filter(c => c != null)

val dataToStoreInit = csv.select(columns: _*)
val partitionColumn = job.partitionKeyColumns.get(0)
val dataToStore =   dataToStoreInit.repartition(dataToStoreInit(partitionColumn))

dataToStore.write
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
.options(Map("table" -> job.outTableName, "keyspace" -> keyspace))
.mode(SaveMode.Append)
.save()

spark.stop()
```

Comment: Can you please click on the details in the dag and attach the screen shots

Comment: Unfortunately job got completed, and I was unable to take the screenshot, is there a way if i can get that information from logs